# Letting user decide what operation to apply to a list of numbers

Tags: python

I have picked up Python recently and was wondering how I could do the following. Say we have a list of 3 numbers:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
```

Then, we ask the user what to do with these numbers:

```
whatdo = raw_input('> ')
```

For example the user enters '+2'. Now how do I apply '+ 2' to all the elements of the list?

Comment: What's going on with the title? It has nothing to do with your question…

Answer (score 6):

```
import operator as oper

operations = {
    '+': oper.add,
    '-': oper.sub,
    '*': oper.mul
}

numbers = [1, 2, 3]

op, num1 = raw_input("> ").split()
num1 = int(num1)
op = operations[op]

y = [op(num1, num2) for num2 in numbers]
print y

--output:--
> * 30
[30, 60, 90]
```

Comment: @Alenta Urentio, Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

A more generic possibility would be to let the user specify a function, and use Python's [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) statement to turn the string into an actual [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) function.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
function = raw_input('> Please specify f(x): ')
f = eval("lambda x: " + function)
print map(f, numbers)
```

Example:

```
> Please specify f(x): (x+1)**2
[4, 9, 16]
```

Of course, this allows the user to specify all kinds of invalid or even malicious "functions", so this should be handled with care.